# How to deploy Google Cloud Function with shared local dependencies?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, python-import

I am having some trouble with local modules when deploying on Cloud Functions - any ideas or best practices would be appreciated!

I am trying to deploy a piece of my project as a Cloud Function. It uses some local code from the project, which is shared with other modules - and I use an absolute import for that. I am using a Cloud Repository for deployment, and there I state the folder where the function resides (`parent\cloud_function\`). The problem is the parent package is not available with that setup.

This is an example of the project structure:

```
├── parent_repo
│   ├── parent
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── config.conf
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── cloud_function
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── main.py
│   │   │   └── requirements.txt
│   │   ├── shared_module
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── package1.py
│   │   │   └── package2.py
│   │   ├── other_module
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── some_script.py
│   │   │   └── another_script.py
│   │   └── utils.py
```

inside `parent.cloud_function.main.py` AND in `parent.other_module.some_script.py` I use:

```
from parent.shared_module.package1 import some_func
from parent.shared_module.package2 importsome_class
```

to access shared code. However, when trying to deploy the function on Cloud Functions, since I assume it only looks at the folder alone, the `parent` module is unavailable.

Of course I could simply nest all required code inside the `cloud_function` folder - but from a project perspective that isn't ideal - as that code is shared across other resources, and does not logically belong there.

Does anyone have a good idea how to this better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Very shortly - it is difficult.

Here is [Python runtime - Specifying dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime#specifying_dependencies) description -

> requirements.txt file or packaging local dependencies alongside your
> function

You probably can play with [Private dependencies in the Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies)

Some ideas are provided in the [Deploy a Python Cloud Function with all package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546098/deploy-a-python-cloud-function-with-all-package-dependencies/56548706) SO question.

Comment: Thanks @al-dann - I'll look into it, and repost my final setup when done, for future ref. Moved on to something else for now, but will circle back eventually. Thanks again!

Comment: The "pip install -t" solution seems weird, isn't pip building stuff for local environment? What if I'm on ARM and GCP is not ARM?