# Using glpk solver in google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pyomo, glpk

I m wondering if there is any solution to use glpk solver with Pyomo in a google cloud function. and I'm wondering if there is any alternatif solution to solve an optimization problem using a Cloud function

Comment: Have you gotten the code to run on a local version of python? Packages can be installed in Google Cloud as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546098/deploy-a-python-cloud-function-with-all-package-dependencies).

Comment: yes, but glpk it is a solver not a pip package